# Are there any open questions in physics that a layman can analyze?

Tags: soft-question, research-level

In math, there are questions like "What is the minimum number of crosses that this knot has?" which can't fundamentally be solved and simply take a lot of trial and error for an answer. This means that a layman can enter the field fairly easily and study it if they wish to. Are there any open problems in physics with that sort of leniency?

To clarify, by "that a layman can analyze", I mean that "a layman can get a logically consistent answer to without necessarily requiring higher-level theory".

For example: Here is a video on knots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqyyhhnGraw. That is about as much as I know about knot theory.

My knowledge of knot theory can barely be considered rudimentary. But I know what a knot is, and how they are classified. I also know that it is impossible to be sure that a knot has the least number of crossings, and thus it takes a lot of trial and error to check on these knots.

I could contribute to the theory by building and constructing structures physically matching theoretical knots and manipulating that rather than using topological transformations. Something like building a theoretical knot using the same material as a rubber band and looking to see if one can find less crossings than what is considered the minimum. This does not require theory, a layman can do it, and it [could] be a novel attempt, especially for the more complex ones. It is at least useful to the field at that point because finding the least number of crossings is trial and error and perseverance after the structure is made.

Now this is perhaps not the best analogy, but I think the point is made that a layman *can* contribute to knot theory in that manner. The layman has the wherewithal.

So the question is, is there anything a layman can contribute to physics research without necessarily requiring the use of theory taught in higher-level classes? I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: I've deleted some chatty comments; remember that comments are meant for requesting clarification, suggesting improvements, and sometimes linking to related resources.

Comment: There are a number of experimental contributions that can be made, not theorectical. There is crowd sourcing of observations in astronomy http://www.americanscientist.org/science/pub/crowdsourcing-astronomy-with-galaxy-zoo , and also an attempt was made with crowdsourcing for data from the ATLAS experiment at LHC https://daily.zooniverse.org/2014/11/26/higgs-hunters-is-here/ . One could search for similar projects.